# How to flip an image with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I have an idea for a website front page for my wife's jewelry. I want it to be very simple. There is a blurred background with the title on top. In the middle of the page are a few divs with text (necklaces/rings/etc.). My idea is that when the user hovers over "necklaces" a square with that portion of the background image and the text flips around and an image of a necklace is on the back of that square. Then I want the user to click on the image which will take them to the landing page for that product.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: To be more specific...I have a background image that fills the entire screen. I want to take a 200x200px div from that background image and have the backside of that 200x200 display a different image which is also a link. the davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php was the best help so far. I just want to know if that can be applied to the above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you can flip images with CSS3 using the `transform`property.

```
img:hover{
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

This will flip your image vertically on hover of the image. You can also use `scaleX(-1)` to flip it horizontally.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L6mojwdt/

Comment: And with animation: http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/L6mojwdt/1/

Comment: And with animation both ways :) http://jsfiddle.net/L6mojwdt/3/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're going for but you can look at this fiddle and let me know. You definitely are going to want to use the `rotateX` and `rotateY` for this in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/5kk0d0q4/1/